# Can I use same bitcoin address for Mt.Gox deposit multiple times?

Tags: transactions, address, mtgox

They say they will generate new address for each deposit. If I want to split my bitcoin transaction in multiple parts but send one after another, can I use the same address more often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. The reason for using different address every time is:

- to provide you more anonymity. It will be harder for people to
  associate your with your other addresses (but not impossible)

But if you need to make many transactions, it might be a little bit tedious. So it is up to you to decide what exactly do you want.